# C++ declare 'main' as a reference to function?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

What if I define main as a reference to function?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main1()
{
    cout << "Hello World from main1 function!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int (&main)() = main1;
```

What will happen? I tested in an online compiler with error "Segmentation fault":

[here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s39eTgnV0jiqR4PL)

And under VC++ 2013 it will create a program crashing at run-time!

A code calling the data of the function pointer as a code will be compiled which will immediately crash on launch.

**I would also like an ISO C++ standard quote about this.**

*The concept will be useful if you want to define either of 2 entry-points depending on some macro like this:*

```
int main1();

int main2();

#ifdef _0_ENTRY
int (&main)() = main1;
#else
int (&main)() = main2;
#endif
```

Comment: _"What will happen? I tested in an online compiler with error 'Segmentation fault'"_ You just answered your own question, did you not??

Comment: You're excluding freestanding implementations, correct?

Comment: It's not an ISO C++ standard quote but http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function is usually pretty accurate. It says specifically that main is a special function and one of those 'special' properties is that it's address cannot be taken.

Comment: I think you're asking for a lot to hope that the ISO standard comments on such an insane behavior.

Comment: @qeadz How do you take one's address in a declaration?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Why? It may be insane, but the point of an ISO standard is to specify such things in detail.

Comment: Amusingly, the standard doesn't actually prohibit code built within a freestanding implementation from defining a global symbol called `main` that is not a function, although it does impose other reservations on the symbol while in that namespace.

Comment: @qeadz: Nobody is taking the address of a function `main`, here.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The Standard already spans over 1300 pages. If it had to specify in detail every insane thing a programmer would want to do, nobody would read it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl For the same reason that the standard won't comment on the invalidity of many other oddball things that people might try to do.  It doesn't try to comment on every case.  It gives a standard framework of operations.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Actually it comments on every case that is allowed, and then it says the rest are UB. So that's pretty good coverage. By definition, the standard leaves nothing untouched (as long as you include "is UB" in your definition of "having been touched by the standard").

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right.

Comment: @remyabel: As a matter of fact, as the answers to the questions show, the standard *does* define whether the OP's code is allowed or not. It has to; by definition, the standard covers every imaginable piece of code and tells you whether it is valid or not. IWO, there is no piece of code, no matter how insane, of which the standard says "I don't care if this is undefined behaviour or not".

Comment: @ChristianHackl Where in the standard then does it say you can't declare a reference to `main`? Nowhere. It's implicitly prohibited. (And if something is blatantly missing from the standard, it's probably a defect.)

Comment: It is not a reference to 'main' but a global variable named 'main' which is a reference to function. I was mistaken too so changed question title.

Comment: @remyabel: It says that in [basic.start.main]/3. "The function `main` shall not be used within a program." That includes using it to initialise a reference. (Not that that has anything to do with the question, which is about what kind of entity `main` is allowed to be.)

Comment: @remyabel: Of course it's implicit, yes. The standard probably also does not say explicitly that `std::vector` does not have a `foo` member function, yet you can quote a passage which lists all member functions to explain why `v.foo()` is invalid.

Comment: Could you please integrate information into the question so that it forms a single coherent post? Rather than a timeline of edits....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not a conformant C++ program.  C++ requires that (section 3.6.1)

> A  program  shall  contain  a  global  function  called  `main`

Your program contains a global not-a-function called `main`, which introduces a name conflict with the `main` function that is required.

---

One justification for this would be it allows the hosted environment to, during program startup, make a function call to `main`.  It is not equivalent to the source string `main(args)` which could be a function call, a function pointer dereference, use of `operator()` on a function object, or construction of an instance of a type `main`.  Nope, `main` must be a function.

One additional thing to note is that the C++ Standard never says what the type of `main` actually is, and prevents you from observing it.  So implementations can (and do!) rewrite the signature, for example adding any of `int argc, char** argv, char** envp` that you have omitted.  Clearly it couldn't know to do this for your `main1` and `main2`.

Comment: Your quote is incomplete. Immediately thereafter is stated _"It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function."_ And there is no rule that such a program cannot define another kind of entity in the global namespace called `main` (p3: "A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is illformed. The name main is not otherwise reserved. [ Example: member functions, classes, and enumerations can be called main, as can entities in other namespaces. —end example ]").

Comment: That being said, I think we can assume the OP isn't using such an implementation. :) But perhaps all this would improve this answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's interesting that they chose to write this rule as a universal statement followed by a contradiction, without so much as an "except".  It surely wouldn't have been difficult to say "A program in a hosted environment shall contain a global function called `main`" or "A program shall contain a global function called `main`, except that in a freestanding environment it is implementation-defined..."

Comment: I agree. The wording has always bothered me (and seems to lead to a few internet arguments when it's subsequently misinterpreted!).

Answer (score 7):

> This would be useful if you want to define either of 2 entry-points depending on some macro

No, not really. You should do this:

```
int main1();
int main2();

#ifdef _0_ENTRY
   int main() { return main1(); }
#else
   int main() { return main2(); }
#endif
```

Comment: Yep but assigning just a function reference seems more intuative for me at least. Otherwise we are defining another function which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: That's a nice and unobstrusive solution.

Comment: @FISOCPP: I really don't see why not. Besides, you do not have a choice. :)

Comment: I never said that this is bad. I just feel that mine version seems more intuative.

Comment: @FISOCPP: I don't think your version is intuitive at all, but each to their own, I guess.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks; whoops ;) BTW check out the highlighting in the answer's diff; good job SO lol

Answer (score 3):

This is soon going to become clearly ill-formed, thanks to the resolution of [CWG issue 1886](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1886), currently in "tentatively ready" status, which adds, among other things, the following to [basic.start.main]:

> A program that declares a variable `main` at global scope or that
>   declares the name `main` with C language linkage (in any namespace) is
>   ill-formed.

Comment: Prehaps they should better allow 'main' function references as exception to the rule.

Comment: @FISOCPP: That would be prohibitively complex to implement. `main` must be a simple function that may be invoked by the C++ runtime. Introducing complexities like you're proposing is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen in practice is highly dependent on the implementation.

In your case your compiler apparently implements that reference as a "pointer in disguise". In addition to that, the pointer has external linkage.  I.e. your program exports an external symbol called `main`, which is actually associated with memory location in data segment occupied by a pointer. The linker, without looking too much into it, records that memory location as the program's entry point.

Later, trying to use that location as an entry point causes segmentation fault. Firstly, there's no meaningful code at that location. Secondly, a mere attempt to pass control to a location inside a data segment might trigger the "data execution protection" mechanisms of your platform.

By doing this you apparently hoped that the reference will get optimized out, i.e. that `main` will become just another name for `main1`. In your case it didn't happen. The reference survived as an independent external object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already answered the question about what happens.

As far as why, in your code `main` is a reference/pointer to a function. That is different than a function. And I would expect a segment fault if the code is calling a pointer instead of a function.